# Azure SQL Database gives Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We are running an Azure SQL Database across two machines, geo replicated (read only replicas). Sometimes we get a common SQL error:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__transact__3213E82229255808'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.owners'. The duplicate key value is (428178d0-1234-4846-871c-769a3c40c884).
```

which normally I would have no problem of solving. However, the only code that inserts/updates stuff to that table is the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM owners WHERE id = @ownerId)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO owners
    (
        id
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @ownerId
    )

END
ELSE 
BEGIN

    UPDATE    owners 

    SET        
    ...
            updatedAt = GETDATE()

    WHERE    id = @ownerId

END

...

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

(I have removed some unrelated code)

The code seems all perfect and my only option left is that there is some strange stuff going on with the replication. Am I missing something here?

Comment: How is `@ownerId` generated?

Comment: BTW, is this relevant question/answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076654/violation-of-primary-key-constraint-during-merge-replication ?

Comment: It comes from an external source. It is a uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Nope, sorry, I cannot see how the q/a in that link is relevant. (Thanks anyways)

Comment: Is your external source really random? I have seen similar bug when virtual machines were cloned with the same entropy source - can it be

Comment: But it shouldn´t matter. Since I have the IF NOT EXISTS() thing, there will only be an update if the id already exists.

Comment: Not really - concurrent insert can happen in short period between IF and INSERT.

Comment: True, but this code is within a transaction (see the code example), so that should be impossible.

Comment: It depends on transaction isolation level.

Comment: Aha, now we are getting somewhere :) Which levels would ensure that the insert will not fail?

Comment: Maybe using something like suggested in first reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807640/using-try-catch-to-perform-insert-update (i.e. do the update first, then check for @rowcount = 0 and instead do an insert) is better because I don´t have to change isolation level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110391/discussion-between-sten-and-ginden).